# Cannot go back to in-development iOS app after email verified Firebase Dynamic Links

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, email-verification

I'm new to Firebase Dynamic Links but I cannot figure out how to reach an unpublished app I'm working at after verifying email using Firebase Auth. I went through all setup steps and lots of other questions on this website and I cannot get this going.

```
public static func sendVerificationEmail(authResult: AuthDataResult?, completion: @escaping CompletionBlock) {
    if let user = authResult?.user {
        if !user.isEmailVerified {
            let actionCodeSettings =  ActionCodeSettings.init()
            actionCodeSettings.handleCodeInApp = false
            actionCodeSettings.url =
                URL(string: String(format: "https://myapp.page.link/verifyEmail"))
            actionCodeSettings.setIOSBundleID("com.company.myappname")
            actionCodeSettings.dynamicLinkDomain = "myapp.page.link"
            user.sendEmailVerification(with: actionCodeSettings) { error in
                completion(error == nil)
            }
        } else {
            completion(true)
        }
    } else {
        completion(false)
    }
}
```

I set handleCodeInApp to false because i wanted to directly verify email without accessing "Preview page" of FDL first, which didn't make any sense. When reaching email verified successfully page, I got a continue button which I guess holds the continue url attached to email verification link(https://myapp.page.link/?link=https://myapp.page.link/verifyEmail), and then it goes to the "open link in app" page, where it brings me to the app store page and says that app is not available (created profile on appstoreconnect to get app store id) or to the app store page of a published app if set its app store id to the firebase app (even though the published one is installed - I guess that's because handleCodeInApp is false). Regarding the deeplink of myapp.page.link/verifyEmail Dynamic Link, if I set a custom one it shows me "Site not found" error. Can someone please help me sort this out?

Also, when accessing debug mode of FDL, it gives me the following warning: 
[FDL debug warning image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsbFc.png)

Device OS: iOS 13.3.1
Xcode: 11.3.1
Firebase iOS SDK: 6.18.0

Many thanks.

Comment: I somehow managed to fix it by creating another FDL domain.

Comment: Do not put Solved in the title. If you solved it, answer your own question or delete it.